# Passing column name to parameter

Tags: sql

I have a table with ticketID, clientmachineName and UserName columns.
i need to write a stored procedure where i have to pass each column name as parameter and value also as parameter.

It should write output query as

```
select * from table where @cloumn=@value.
```

can anyone help please..

Comment: You need dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why cant the client app build the right sql query and only parameterize `@value`?

Answer (score 0):

you will need dynamic SQL like:

```
DECLARE @myquery varchar(1000) = 'select * from table where ' + @column + '=''' + @value + ''''
EXEC @myquery
```